# Sorting a pandas DataFrame by a Series, without a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to work out the cleanest way to deal with this issue.

I have a pandas DataFrame. I know that it contains columns `x` and `y` but it **may** contain other columns. I would very much prefer to ignore these if they exist, leaving them untouched.

As a simplified version of my problem. Let's say I want to sort this DataFrame by the difference between `x` and `y`.

Currently I do the following:

```py
def sort_diff(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df['xy'] = abs(df.x - df.y)
    df = df.sort_values('xy')
    df = df.drop('xy')
    return df
```

Now this isn't terrible, but it overwrites `xy`. This is a column that may or may not exist. The problem is I don't know.

My current options, based on my limited knowledge of pandas, are:

- Reserve `xy` as a special column name
- Use some messy(ish) temporary column name to avoid conflict (`tmp_xy_diff`)
- Check if it exists, save it if it does, and write it back afterwards.

So what I'm asking is if there's any way to do this sort without crushing a random column on the table. Like, can I use an ordered series (with matching indexes) to define the order of a new dataframe? If I can do something like that, is the performance noticeably worse?

Something like:

```py
def sort_diff(df):
    diffs = (abs(df.x - df.y)).sort_values()
    return df.become_this(diffs.index)
```

Comment: In the last fragment you can return something like `df.reindex(diffs.index)` or `df.loc[diffs.index]`. Both should be quite performant.

Comment: @MohamedThasinah Who says `sort_diff` gets a copy? If I edit `df` without reassigning it to a copy, I will edit the DataFrame passed into. I'm trying to avoid side effects like that. Python passes a reference by value, so reassigning it breaks the reference and I no longer edit the original. As for `xy`. I stated: `This is a column that may or may not exist. The problem is I don't know.` That's the whole problem. I don't know if it exists. I'd rather operate in a way that means I don't have to know.

Comment: @ayhan You can just use `df.loc[diffs.index]`!!!! I totally did not know that! I also didn't know about reindex, which seems useful in a few edge cases I have. If you write that up as an answer I'll select it as correct.

Comment: @MohamedThasinah The answer is pretty much what I stated: `The short answer is, Python always does pass-by-value, but every Python variable is actually a pointer to some object, so sometimes it looks like pass-by-reference.`

That's what I mean when I say Python passes a reference by value. It always passes by value, but that value is a reference. Reassignments (`df = 1`) edit the value, and do not follow the reference.